# Text not displaying properly in LWJGL (2D over 3D)

Tags: java, text, unicode, fonts, lwjgl

I have a problem with the text not displaying properly on my screen, It appears as a blank rectangle with the same text color, Just no text...
Everything else works fine though, Menus and crosshair and other 2D stuff renders fine. I'm using this tutorial: http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL

getting this result: [image: As you can see in the top left corner, It displays text as a rectangle, This is supposed to display the FPS, But it's just a moving rectangle.]

EDIT: I managed to fix that issue, But now I have another problem, Text is displaying with a black background, Like this guys issue: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=26944.0

but his fix which is disabling depth test does not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the order in which your objects are rendered.
To make sure it works correctly they should be rendered in back to front order. See [here](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Are you enabling GL_BLEND? If so, try setting `glDepthMask(false);` after the `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`.